# Best way to draw graphs with Three.js

Tags: three.js

I would like to draw graphs with Three.js and wonder what is the best way for it.

This framework here https://github.com/davidpiegza/Graph-Visualization solves it in using spheres as nodes and lines as edges.

I would need to add labels to the edges or alternatively can select the edges.

What other ways are there to draw graphs? Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: Did you find a good solution?

Answer (score 23):

You should check out MathBox http://acko.net/blog/making-mathbox/ (which is based on three.js and the author's shader library ShaderGraph.js). The MathBox uses his library for many of this interactive 3d Math examples found on his blog. http://acko.net/blog/