# Creating magnetic field lines of a sphere (eg. earth) in three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am currently trying to make physics experiments in three.js. I wish to make magnetic field lines of a sphere. I have searched about bezier curves but am not quite sure how to implement it. What I wish to achieve is something like this :

[Examples of what I want](https://www.google.co.in/search?biw=1190&bih=624&tbm=isch&sa=1&q=magnetic%20field%20lines%20of%20earth&oq=magnetic%20field%20lines%20of%20earth&gs_l=img.3..0.9477.12727.0.12957.10.5.1.4.5.0.185.638.1j4.5.0....0...1c.1.64.img..0.9.545.pNJ1tjoK0nc#imgrc=v4Zy9Snd3uU7SM%3A)

This is a 2d version but i would like a 3d version of the same.

Comment: Do you already have the mathematics to draw the correct lines?

Comment: I am not sure about the mathematical equations. However if you know a way to plot mathematical functions, do tell. I just have to show that magnetic field lines come out from the north and enter in the south. Although it is known that these field lines are elliptical in nature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the math for calculating the points you can use a spline to draw the magnetic lines like this:

```
// Array of THREE.Vector3 points created using your math
var points = [ v1, v2, v3, v4, etc ];

var curve = new THREE.SplineCurve3( points );
var geometry = new THREE.Geometry();

// Set the amount of segments, the higher the number the smoother the line.
geometry.vertices = curve.getPoints( 50 );

var material = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial( { color : 0xff0000 } );

// Create the final Object3d to add to the scene
var splineObject = new THREE.Line( geometry, material );
```

This comes straight out of the docs and can be found [here](http://threejs.org/docs/#Reference/Extras.Curves/SplineCurve3)

---

Also interesting for you might be **[MathBox](http://acko.net/blog/making-mathbox/)** which is also mentioned in [this answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14925017/1697459).